# Delete multiple entries from a list given a list of indices

Tags: python, numpy-slicing

I have a list of indices and a list of data. The list of indices says which elements should be removed from the list of data. I would like to use the list of indices efficiently, i.e. without loops. Is there a faster way to remove these elements?

Comment: What does this have to do with numpy?

Comment: All lists have indices. What do mean by "list of indices"?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it without loops. Sort the list of indices from highest to lowest. Loop through them, calling `list_of_data.pop(index)` on each.

Comment: @BenAlan He means a list containing indexes into the list of data.

Comment: As per @Barmar's answer, or `a = [x for i,x in enumerate(a) if i not in indices]`, assuming `a` is your data list and `indices` is your indices list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use numpy, [`np.delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) does exactly what you want:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36])
>>> np.delete(a, [1, 2, 5])
array([ 1, 16, 25])
```